Does type-casting each element of an array takes less space than copying the array into a new one?
I am currently writing a program where given two input matrices (int8_t and float respectively) I compute the multiplication of the two.
For memory reasons, I do not want the entire int8 matrix to be converted to a floating type (or any type that occupies more than 8bits in memory). I believe that in C, when multiplying int with float, there is an implicit type casting that is done to convert int to float, in order to do the operation.
My question now is, if I cast my int8 input as a float, then do the computation, what is actually happening in the memory ?
Is it over-writing other useless memory spaces when the cast is done, or is it taking additional place as if I created a float array in which I copied my data ?
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int l = 0; l < k; ++l) {
            sum += (float) input_a[i*k + l] * input_b[l*m + j];
        }
        output[i*m + j] = sum;
    }
} 


Please also show your declarations of input_a, input_b, output. Then you might be able to answer this question yourself.

I do not understand how this relates to my question ? Could you explain it a bit better?
I want to know if memory-wise type casting each element of an array is the same as copying the entire array ?

I'm pretty sure that creating one float at a time will reuse the same space for that single value. There is llittle reason to "save it for later" and use a new space each time in the loop.

@Elyon what I mean is that you allocate memory in the declaration, e.g. in int arr1[10] you allocate 10 integers (with sizeof(int) bytes) and in float arr2[10] you allocate 10 floats (with sizeof(float)bytes each). The type cast in sum += (float) ... only uses temporarily "some" space (stack memory or registers) but that's not what really matters for the memory consumption of your application.

If you copied the input_a array to float copy_a[…]; and then did the calculation using copy_a instead of input_a, you would only convert the values from int8_t to float once.  With the code as written, you convert the elements of input_a each time you use them.  There's a time-space trade-off — and only you have enough information to tell whether making that one-time conversion would be a major performance benefit.  If space is constrained, what you have is fine.  If time is more of a concern, you could try using the converted copy and see whether that speeds up operations.

To be clear, the compiler won't do the conversion copying for you — that would be outside its remit.  But you could decide to do it.

sum += (float) input_a[i*k + l] * input_b[l*m + j]; specifies a computation to be performed. It overtly says to fetch element i*k + l of input_a, convert it to float, fetch element l*m + j of input_b, multiply these (including an implicit conversion of the second operand to float), add them to sum, and store the result in sum.
Nothing in this says to store anything into any memory other than sum. The C standard allows a compiler to implement this computation in any way that does not alter the observed behavior of the program, which consists of its output, its input/output interactions, and accesses to volatile objects. With most compilers and most processors, the compiler will generate code to perform this operation entirely in processor registers:

The subscripts will be calculated in processor registers.
The array elements will be loaded into processor registers.
The values will be converted to float in processor registers.
The multiplication and addition will be performed in processor registers.
The result will either be stored to sum in memory or compiler optimization will keep sum in a processor registers until the final output[i*m + j] = sum; is performed.

In somewhat unusual, yet not extraordinary circumstances, the compiler may use additional memory:

Depending on availability of processor registers and the context of surrounding code, the compiler may have to save some processor registers to the hardware stack to free up the registers for the computations required in this loop. This will be at most a few stores before the loops and a few loads afterward.
In some processors with strict separations between integer and floating-point registers, the compiler may need to use memory to transfer data between them.

In no ordinary C implementation would the compiler generate an entire array of float elements to hold the various values that this code converts to float.

Most computers have a small number of dedicated memory regions inside the processor called registers. They’re used for scratch work when performing computation and typically there’s only a handful of them (think on the order of 10-100): not nearly enough space to hold a huge array, but definitely enough space to process an individual array element. This memory is not in RAM and is instead physically built into the CPU.
Typically, when you typecast an integer to a float in the middle of an expression, the processor will store the resulting float in a register just long enough to use that value when computing the rest of the expression. If you do this in a loop, usually, but not always, the CPU will use the same register on each iteration of the loop to hold the temporary floating point value. In that sense, no new memory is needed at all if you perform the typecast inside the loop.
Now, I say “usually” and “typically” above because this isn’t guaranteed to happen. The structure of your code might be such that there are no registers available at the time you need them. The optimizer inside the compiler might see what you’re trying to do and rewrite your code in some other way. But realistically it’s a safe bet that you’ll get a register here, and if not it’ll be a very small amount of RAM likely reused from iteration to iteration.
On the other hand, if you make a brand-new array of n floats and do all the typecasts at once, you will likely end up using up n × sizeof(float) bytes of storage because you’ve explicitly asked for space to put n floats. The memory you get back will probably be in RAM because there’s too many floats to give each one a register. So you should assume that approach will require more memory. If you’re dealing with gigabytes of data, that approach may be prohibitive.
I’ve said “probably” and “likely” here because optimizing compilers these days are getting really good at what they do and it’s possible the compiler will see that you need the array only for the purposes of the loop and thus rewrite your code to just do typecasts. But it’s probably not good to rely on that.
